# Line Chart with jQuery Flot (Fix Start Time)

Tags: jquery, time, flot

I have created a bar chart with jQuery Flot. It is a real time chart which starts with the current time and updates with time. I want to change the x-axis of this chart so that the start time does not disappear when it starts plotting, and it do some scaling after too many time intervals come on the x-axis.

Here is the chart I created  [Chart Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zstmK/1/)

My data is int this form

```
  function GetData() {
        var fast = parseInt(msg[1]);
    var ok = parseInt(msg[2]);
    var slow = parseInt(msg[3]);
    var data = [
           {label: "Fast", data:fast},
           {label: "OK", data:ok},
           {label: "Slow", data:slow}
    ];
        return data;
  }
```

Can any one please help me out ?

Thanks

```
  Click on "Chart Link" to see the running chart
```

Comment: So you don't want it to shift the front points off as new points are added?  What happens after it updates for a long period of time?  Cool chart by the way.

Comment: yes i dont want to shift the starting point as new points come , if it updates for a long period it should scale the time on x-axis

Comment: See answer below.  It will autoscale with more points, going to get really crowded after a while...

Answer (score 1):

In `GetData` just remove the "shifting" of the data:

```
// I commented out 3 lines!
function GetData() {
  //data.shift(); 
  //while (data.length < totalPoints) {     
    var y = Math.random() * 100;
    var temp = [now += updateInterval, y];
    data.push(temp);
  //}
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zstmK/2/).

Comment: Please see my edited question how my data look like ... but its not plotting

Comment: Did you modify anything else in the JSFiddle.  Your GetData() now returns something before it modified a global...

Comment: kindly check th JSFiddle now, Actually the data comes from the back end , The 3 variables slow, fast and ok come from backend which specify the speed of event and comes to this page everytime the event speed is modified

Comment: Not to be a asshole but your jsFiddle has multiple javascript errors.  Have you debugged your code (and looked at Javascript errors)?  You have to put a little effort in here...

Comment: I dont see any errors in my console I debuged the data its coming correct but the time is not moving and hence nothing is plotted. If you want I can show u the updated code

Comment: With the link above I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.flot.time.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , fiddle.jshell.net:54`

Comment: I created a new chart but the time line is not moving Can you please help me in that if I show u my new code ?

Comment: I cant believe it, it is moving here http://jsfiddle.net/zstmK/20/ but not in my code :(

Comment: I have written it inside $(document).ready(function(){} will it make any difference ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34767/discussion-between-mark-and-umair-iqbal)